# JUnit testing returning primitive types

Tags: java, list, junit, double, tdd

I am working on unit testing with JUnit. For this particular test case we check if our basket or list is empty then we should return a price of `0.0`. If the calculatePrice method of the checkout is passed an empty Basket, it should return a price, as a double of `0.0`.
Im just not sure how to go about this. I'm more or less trying to ensure that the price is `0.0` when you check the basket but I feel totally off on something.

```java
public class Basket {
    
    private List<Object> bookList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    
    public List<Object> getBooksInBasket() {
        return bookList;
    }

}
```

```java
public class CheckOut {
    
    private double price = 0.0;
    
    public double getCheckOutPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    double calculatePrice(Basket basket) {
        Basket basket1 = new Basket();
        if(((List<Object>) basket1).size()==0)
            return basket.price1=0.0;
        return price;
        
        //return null;
    }
}
```

```java
public class CheckOutTest {

    @Test
    public void test_CalculatePrice_ReturnsDoubleZeroPointZeroWhenPassedAnEmptyBasket() {
        //Arrange
        Basket basket = new Basket();
        CheckOut checkout = new CheckOut();
        
        //Act       
        checkout.calculatePrice(basket);
        
        //Assert
        
        //assertEquals(0.0,checkout.price);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the statement     if(((List<Object>) basket1).size()==0)
works well?

Comment: @GarimaGupta most likely not. Trying to figure out how i can incorporate the basket list into the checkout method atm

Answer (score 1):

> I'm more or less trying to ensure that the price is 0.0 when you check the basket but i feel totally off on something

```
assertEquals(0.0,checkout.price);
```

That looks pretty reasonable to me (aside from the clear typo that the test is trying to read from a private member).

Assertions of floating point and double precision floating point numbers can be tricky when rounding rules get involved, but there is nothing wrong with asserting that you get an exact answer in a use case where no rounding is expected.

Your implementation of Checkout *is* a little bit odd, in the context of TDD.  There's a lot more code there than is motivated by this single test, and the API of `Checkout` doesn't quite match what you've written in this test.  That leaves you with an implementation that doesn't quite look like it is test driven.